# Gradle TestNG suite files are not running

Tags: gradle, testng

I am new to gradle and I am stuck at running my testsuite using gradle. Below are my files:

I am getting Build Successful Message but my scripts are not running. I have configured in testNG.xml which all test cases to run,but gradle is not picking up the xml file and the tests which are defined in it.

```
Build.gradle file:
task createTest(type: Test) {

    test {
        useTestNG() {
            suites 'src/test/resources/testNG.xml'

            useDefaultListeners = true
        }
    }
}


and my testNG file is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="liveScoreTesting" parallel="tests" thread-count="6">


    <listeners>


        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
        <listener class-name="support.ReportingTools" />
    </listeners>


    <parameter name="browser" value="FF" />
    <parameter name="timeout" value="45" />
    <parameter name="driverLocation"
               value="src/test/resources/ChromeDriverServerx32/chromedriver.exe"></parameter>
    <parameter name="excelSheetLocation"
               value="/src/test/resources/DataSheets/LiveScoreValidationTest.xls" />
    <parameter name="sheetName" value="dataProvider" />
    <parameter name="suppressScreenshot" value="true" />

    <test name="LiveScoreTest" enabled="true" verbose="5">
        <parameter name="excelSheetLocation"
                   value="/src/test/resources/DataSheets/LiveScoreValidationTest.xls" />
        <parameter name="sheetName" value="dataProvider" />
        <classes>
            <class name="Scripts.LiveScoreValidationTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="HeadlessBrowserTesting" enabled="false" verbose="5">
        <parameter name="browser" value="PHANTOM" />
        <parameter name="driverLocation"
                   value="src/test/resources/PhantomJSServer/bin/phantomjs.exe"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="Scripts.HeadlessBrowserTesting1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    </suite>




Everytime I run the task it says Build Successful but does not run my test cases.
Note :  I dont want to use directly this solution-

 task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: '`enter code here`classes') {


        main = 'org.testng.TestNG'
        classpath = files("./src/test/resources",
                project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.test.compileClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath)


        args = ["-parallel", "methods", "-threadcount", "1", "-d", "./build/test-output", "./src/test/resources/TestNGFiles/testNG.xml"]


    }
    enter code here

}

as using this I am not able to disable the default test listener. Appreciate your quick response.
```

Comment: How does your gradle command look like?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. I had an existing gradle config that used TestNG for testing and I decided I wanted it to use an XML config rather than running all tests in each class under src/test (which is the default behavior).

Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, and then it hit me.

**Gradle does incremental builds.** Nothing was happening because all of the test results were (as far as Gradle was concerned) up-to-date.

Did a 'gradle clean' first, then ran the tests. That worked. (Can't believe I didn't figure that out earlier, LOL)